# How to use an XSL variable for a div's id value

Tags: xslt

I thought the following mark up would work:

```
<div id = '<xsl:value-of select="$TIMEDISPLAY"/>'> </div>
```

I get a bunch of XML documents from an external system. One of the tags contains a timestamp using a certain datetime format. I need to transform the XML to HTML pages that will then be loaded into iframes. I have a javascript function to transform that datetime format to a readable display.

So I though to use XSL to generate each HTML file with its `<script>` section that would locate the id of the div and inject the date display format. For that each HTML file needs to have that div with its own id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not clear, except for this part:

```
<div id = '<xsl:value-of select="$TIMEDISPLAY"/>'> </div>
```

That's invalid syntax. If you want to output a `div` element with an `id` attribute containing the value held in the `$TIMEDISPLAY` variable, you must use one of these:

```
<div>
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="$TIMEDISPLAY"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <!-- some content here -->
</div>
```

or:

```
<div id="{$TIMEDISPLAY}">
    <!-- some content here -->
</div>
```